# Clarification re Principle Component Analysis

Tags: pca, spss

I do understand the principle component analysis. I know how to do it and what it actually does. I have applied PCA and my best result has shown to be two components. I do understand that each of my inputs are now contributing partially in each component. What I do not understand is how to feed the result of PCA (in my case 2 components ) to a machine learning model?
How do we input them?

For example when I want to run a NN on my features, I just can navigate to where they are stored and import them, but my PCA analysis has been run in SPSS and all it shows me is the contribution of my features on each component.

What should I import to my NN model?

Answer (score 0):

PCA is a method of feature extraction, which is used to avoid the problem of co-linearity. For example, if several variables are highly correlated because "they measure the same thing", then PCA can extract a measure of "that thing" (technically: a component), which is called a score. Your data set of, say, 100 measured variables may reduce to, say, 10 significant components. Then you can use the scores your test persons have achieved in those 10 components to do for example a multi-dimensional regression, a cluster analysis or a discriminance analysis. This will result in more valid results than performing the analysis directly on the 100 variables. 
So the procedure is to sort the eigenvalues (and -vectors) by size, identify the number of significant components *p* (e.g., by scree-plot), set up the projection matrix ***F*** (eigenvectors corresponding to the largest *q* eigenvalues in columns) and multiply it with the data matrix ***D***. This will give you the score matrix ***C*** (dimension *n* times *q*, with *n* the number of test persons), which you can use as input for whatever method you want to use next.